# How to verifyElement to the specific span ID element

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-ide, element

I'm using Selenium IDE and need to find a the correct verifyElementPresent to a specific ID element.  For example I need to associate the class "icogreen icon-fioyes" to the id "toy_rule2_checkmark" as of right now.  look at html code below

there will be only be ONE class "icogreen icon-fioyes" (This indicates a green check mark to the lable).  This will change on the website to either

"toy_rule1_checkmark"
"toy_rule2_checkmark"
"toy_rule3_checkmark"

right now i just have this below, but this only targets the green check mark and not to a specific ID

Command:
verifyelementPresent

Target:
//span[contains(@class, 'icogreen icon-nwxyes')]

Thank you in advance

```
<div class="benefits">
  <div id="toy_rule1" class="row even">
    <span id="toy_rule1_checkmark" class="fiono"></span>
    8% of toys sales up to $49.99
  </div>
  <div id="toy _rule2" class="row odd">
    <span id="toy_rule2_checkmark" class="icogreen icon-fioyes" style="background-color: transparent;"></span>
    10% of toys sales $50.00-$149.99
  </div>
  <div id="toy_rule3" class="row even">
    <span id="toy_rule3_checkmark" class="fiono"></span>
    12% of toys with sales $150.00 and above
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the exact question? Do you want to match all the three `toy_ruleX_checkmark` elements?

Comment: Exact question = I do want to match all three toy_rulex_checkmark elements, but not at the same time.  One by one I like to match each elements so each element has the class="icogreen icon-fioyes"